# React Native - How to access promise values from TaskManager in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, taskmanager

I am testing background location tasks in react native with Expo's taskmanager to test when I enter a geofence. I've got the basics working but I am now trying to access the values within a promise that is returned from one of the tasks so i can display if you've entered or exited the geofence. Can anyone help me figure out how to properly access the values I want?

Below is the task portion relevant to the geofence. I return the value region which comes as a promise. I haven't been able to figure out how to send directly from task manager yet:

```
   // 3 Define geofencing task
    TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE, ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
      if (error) {
        // check `error.message` for more details.
        return;
      }
      if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
        console.log("You've entered region:", region);
        //this.props.setEnterRegion({ inRegion: region })
        const final  = region
        return final
      } else if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
        console.log("You've left region:", region);
        const final  = region
        return final
      }
    });
```

Then within App.js I call the app in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getLocationsPermissions();
  this.startBackgroundUpdate();
  this.startGeofence();

}

//define and start geofence
startGeofence = async () => {
  console.log('starting geofencing test ...')
  let x = Location.startGeofencingAsync('TASK_CHECK_GEOFENCE',
    [
    {
      identifier: 'court',
      latitude: this.state.myLocation.latitude,
      longitude: this.state.myLocation.longitude,
      radius: 20,
      notifyOnEnter: true,
      notifyOnExit: true,
     }
     ]
    )

this.sendTask(x)
  
};
```

When I try to access the value I can see the promise and I am unsure where I am going wrong. I would perfer to send to the store directly from taskmanager but I am having trouble with that:

```
//send to store from task
sendTask = (x) => {
  console.log('entered region...', x)
  
  this.props.setEnterRegion(x)

  
entered region... Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```